# How can I make a trigger to click n times when specific elements is clicked?

Tags: jquery, triggers, click, slider

I created a website by using SequenceJS(www.sequencejs.com)

My website can navigate left or right in horizontal.

Once .prev or .next is clicked, it will slide and show the content.

I want to make event when specific element is clicked, the .prev or .next will
click n times.

It's working fine only 1 click.

```
//IF USER CLICK WHY MENU...
$('#why').click(function(){
    if ($(this).parent().hasClass('current')) {
      //Do nothing
    };
    if ($('#detail').parent().hasClass('current')) {
      $('.prev').click(); // Go back 1 slide
      $('#why').parent().addClass('current');
      $('#detail').parent().removeClass('current');
    };
    if ($('#progress').parent().hasClass('current')) {
      $('.prev').click(); // Go back 2 slides.
      $('.prev').click(); // Here, it make it to click 2 times but it doesn't work.
      $('#why').parent().addClass('current');
      $('#progress').parent().removeClass('current');
    };
    if ($('#news').parent().hasClass('current')) {
      $('.prev').click(); //Go back 3 slides
      $('.prev').click(); 
      $('.prev').click(); // This one is not work too.
      $('#why').parent().addClass('current');
      $('#news').parent().removeClass('current');
    };  
});
```

Thanks !!!

Comment: Have you tried using the `goto`, `next` or `previous` functions instead of trying to simulate a user click https://github.com/IanLunn/Sequence/blob/master/documentation.md#public-functions

Comment: Oh. I forgot to look at the documentation. Sorry and thank you. :)